# Get a COM object to throw an exception on any result except S_OK (0) in C#

Tags: c#, com

I'm currently working on an upgrade to a project that extensively uses COM / MFC / (who knows how many other technologies).  As part of the upgrade, we're trying to move as much functionality as we can into managed C# code, but unfortunately some stuff just can't move (for reasons I won't go into).  One of those things is a section of code that grossly abuses COM, and returns pointers in the HRESULTs that later get cast to various other COM-interface implementing objects. I've tried the following code to convert an HRESULT into a pointer that I can then get an interface from :

```
        MyComInterfaceInCS myObj = null;

        try
        {
            world.GetTD_MyComInterfaceInCS();
        }
        catch (COMException comException)
        {
            int pointerValue = Marshal.GetHRForException(comException);

            IntPtr myObjPointer = new IntPtr(pointerValue);

            myObj = (MyComInterfaceInCS) Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(myObjPointer);
        }
```

.... *but*, no COM exception gets thrown, and I'm guessing it's because the pointer is not a negative value, and hence isn't technically a COM error.  Is there any way to configure COM on the object to throw a COM exception on anything BUT S_OK (0) ?

Comment: Pointers in the HRESULT? Wow. Pain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two thoughts:

1. Find and kill (or severely maim)
   whoever implemented this library
2. Implement a wrapper in managed C++
   as you will need to get at the
   method call's HResult directly and I
   cannot think of a way to do that
   using interop.

EDIT

Another option is to declare the COM interfaces in C# such that the signature of each method returns an HRESULT and uses [out retval] for return values. This will alow you to get and examine the HRESULT of all method calls, not just ones that throw a COMException.

By default COM interop typeimport "fixes up" the method signatures such that the HRESULT return is removed on the managed side and the interop layer throws exceptions for E_FAIL etc, essentially throwing away S_OK, S_FALSE and the like.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) has some explanation and the [PreserveSig](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.preservesigattribute%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) attriubte documentation has some additoinal detail.

This will likely require that you declare all of the COM interfaces manually rather than using [tlbimp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx%28VS.80%29.aspx#Y2137) but you may be able to get tlbimp to preserve the signature of the COM methods.

This would allow you to stay purely in C# but in your shoes I'd go with managed C++ as it is just easier to interact with COM in this non-standard fashion from there.